# Mybatis insert custom object

Tags: java, mybatis

In almost all example i found for mybatis, people specify every column for
insertion.I dont want to specify each and every column in the table. Is there 
any way that, when i call addProfile() with user object. All the properties 
mapped and inserted directly into all the columns of the given table ?
I want it this way...

```
@Insert("insert into user values #{user}")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "id")
public int addProfile(User user);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the User object as a parameter in your `addProfile()` method. But the String you specify inside the `@Insert` annotation is a plain SQL statement it does not know the user object you pass into the statement.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439037/1793718) points it clearly,

> MyBatis has auto mapping when reading data from database but doesn't
>   have option to automatically map fields on insertion.
>
> It is possible to have implicit fields in SQL select statement (`select
>   * from table`) so there is automatic mapping to POJO in this case but it is not possible to have implicit fields in update or insert hence
>   no auto-mapping.